# ElasticSearch with MongoDB doesn't indexing big objects

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I created ES (with MongoDB river plugin) index with folowing information:

```
{
    "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
        "db": "mydatabase",
        "collection": "Users"
    },
    "index": {
        "name": "users",
        "type": "user"
    }
}
```

When I insert simple object like:

```
{
   "name": "Joe",
   "surname": "Black"
}
```

Everything work without problem (I can see data using ES Head web interface).
But when I insert bigger object, it doesn't index it:

```
{
    "object": {
        "text": "Let's do it again!",
        "boolTest": false
    },
    "type": "coolType",
    "tags": [
            ""
    ],
    "subObject1": {
        "count": 0,
        "last3": [],
        "array": []
    },
    "subObject2": {
        "count": 0,
        "last3": [],
        "array": []
    },
    "subObject3": {
        "count": 0,
        "last3": [],
        "array": []
    },
    "usrID": "5141a5a4d8f3a79c09000001",
    "created": Date(1363527664000),
    "lastUpdate": Date(1363527664000)
}
```

Where can be problem please?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: This is error from ES console:

> org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping
>   for [stream] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete
>   value been provided to it?    at
>   org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:457)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:486)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:430)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:318)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:157)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:533)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:431)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [2013-03-20
>   10:35:05,697][WARN
>   ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver$Indexer] failed to
>   executefailure in bulk execution: [0]: index [stream], type [stream],
>   id [514982c9b7f3bfbdb488ca81], message [MapperParsingException[object
>   mapping for [stream] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a
>   concrete value been provided to it?]] [2013-03-20 10:35:05,698][INFO
>   ][org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver$Indexer] Indexed 1
>   documents, 1 insertions 0, updates, 0 deletions, 0 documents per
>   second

Comment: Which river are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of MongoDB river are you using?
Please look at issue #26 [1]. It contains examples on indexing large json documents with no issue.

If you can still reproduce the issue please provide more details: river settings, mongodb (version, specific settings), elasticsearch (version, specific settings).

1. https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/issues/26